# Insert into MSSQL from Javascript error with activeXobject

Tags: javascript, sql-server

I am building a dummy application for testing javascript and mssql connections, ive done a similar process using c# and now tried to find a way of doing it with javascript, i found the activeXobject online and just figured out it only worked with IE not chrome.

Not sure what other objects i can use that would work here, i simply want to insert a row into the db while using simple html5 and javascript.

Here is what i have to far...

```
function persistInDB(){
/* Getting access to the database */
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var connectionstring = "Data Source=SQL5036.HostBuddy.com;Initial Catalog=DB_A1F3FA_dominicmazur;User Id=--MYID--;Password=--MYPASS--;";
connection.Open(connectionstring);

/* JavaScript obect to access a SQL query's results */
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

var sql = "INSERT INTO DB_A1F3FA_dominicmazur.dbo.Orders (SIZE,CHEESE,PEPPERONI,HAM,PINEAPPLE,SAUSAGE,FETA,TOMATOE,OLIVES,SUBTOTAL,GST,TOTAL) VALUES ('"+size+"','"+Cheese+"','"+Pepperoni+"','"+Ham+"','"+Pineapple+"','"+Sausage+"','"+Feta+"','"+Tomatoes+"','"+Olives+"','"+cost+"','"+GST+"','"+grandTotal+"')";
alert(sql);
rs.Open(sql, connection);

/* Closing the connections */
//rs.close;
connection.close;
```

}

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

There's no good reason to try to do this from a browser, unless you have some *absurdly* niche requirements. (And any such requirements would probably be better questioned than followed!)

Collect the data on a form and send it to your server using HTML5 & JavaScript, and then do the database operation/s from there.

Comment: Thanks, built it a different way using node.js, a little more work, but way more secure, happy i'm dabbling in node.js now.

Comment: Happy dabbling! ^_^